# My visa application to the UK got refused under 4.2 (a), (c), (e)

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

[image][image] I recently became unemployed and applied for the UK short term standard visitor visa to see my boyfriend who is a British citizen. I provided an invitation letter from his father (because he is the owner of the house) and his ID; my 6 months of bank history with the balance information about my other accounts (yet I failed to prove some of the money that I mentioned in my application). Even though they are only saving accounts, they asked me to show all transaction history and prove the source and provenance of all of my deposits and funds.

Also because I am currently unemployed and unable to prove strong ties to Turkey since I am single with no dependent relatives, and my financial circumstances are not satisfactory, I am also rejected based on lack of incentive to leave the UK.

I am now planning to provide my whole employment history showing all my salaries; full transaction history of all my accounts with an attached letter explaining the times where I exchanged my Turkish liras to Euros to show where the money in my Euro account came to be; a letter from my former employer declaring that I was let go because of economic situations so that they don't think I quit my job with the intent of moving to the UK; and plane tickets to show the exact dates I will be there.

What do you think should be helpful in my situation? I want to be really careful and provide as much information as possible.

Comment: You are not getting a visa to the UK with the profile you have put out here and one refusal in your immediate past. Save yourself the application fee.

Comment: Unemployment + boyfriend in the UK + no ties to home country = a reason to stay in the UK. You are unlikely to be successful second time round

Answer (score 1):

I think your best scenario will be to make plans to see your boyfriend outside of the UK and wait until you have a job to apply for a UK visa. Without strong ties to Turkey, such as a job, family you need to care for, etc..., and a tie to the UK (your boyfriend), you don't have a strong case for a visitor visa at this time.

In addition, if you apply again and are refused, you'll be developing a record of serial refusals, which could hurt your prospects for a visa in the future even when your circumstances are better.

I'd hold off until you have a new job and stronger ties; you'll have a much better change of success.